# Netsuite Suitecloud IDE & Web Services

Tags: netsuite

This isn't much of a programming question, but I figure some here would know the answer.

I'm trying to setup the Suitecloud IDE, but you have to enable Web Services.  Does it cost anything to do so?  Our consultant keeps telling us that we have to buy another account to do so, whereas the Netsuite Tech Support seemed to indicate that it is free.

I'm just wondering what the cost is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it is free.

Go to Setup > Enable Features > Suitecloud (tab) > Web Services (check box).

You have to give roles (or global permissions to users) permission to use Web Services.

You can get the IDE from the help section. Search SuiteCloud IDE and it will come up.

SuiteCloud (Customization, Scripting, and Web Services) >  SuiteCloud IDE >  SuiteCloud IDE Overview

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, your consultant is wrong or at least isn't being clear.

Enabling Web Services(SuiteTalk) doesn't change your licensing costs at all.

When you connect to NetSuite using web services, you do so using a user account.  So in that way, each IDE user would need a license.  In most situations however, if the developers already have access to the NetSuite UI, and are therefore consuming a license, it works fine to have them connect with the IDE using the same credentials and thus the same account. That's what we do anyway.

What's more, you could probably (technically; if not necessarily within the letter of the license agreement) share a single license across all the IDE users.  You would lose all audit control over who made what changes and you could conceivably run into conflicts with multiple users trying to interact with the account at the same time.

Bottom line: SuiteTalk doesn't cost extra to turn on. Anyone with a normal Netsuite user login can use the IDE at no extra cost.